# Why can't I update a Bot Framework Enterprise Template project (v4.0.5-19) to v4.0.8 SDK?

Tags: botframework

I am beginning to explore the new Bot Framework Enterprise Teamplate (v4.0.5-19) and, out of routine, I attempted to update packages after creating the project and I see v4.0.8 of the Bot Builder SDK is available but the Visual Studio 2017 NuGet update fails with the following error:

"Warning    NU1603  EnterpriseBotTest depends on Microsoft.Bot.Builder (>= 4.0.5-19) but Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4.0.5-19 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4.0.6 was resolved."

This is confusing! v4.0.5-19 is installed so ">=" should have been satisfied.  Why can't I update to v4.0.8?

Comment: The template needs to be updated so that is not a preview version (no dashes, e.g. 5-15). What is happening is that it is looking for a newer *preview* version, which it doesn't have.

What you can do in the meantime, is go into your .csproj file, change all Bot.Builder package reference versions from 4.0.5-19 to 4.0.6. Then run the update to the Bot.Builder packages, and then they should be updated to 4.0.8. Once the template itself is updated with a non preview version, this should no longer happen.

Comment: I tried that an now I get the following error:  
Restoring packages for C:\Source\EnterpriseBotTestRHW\EnterpriseBotTestRHW\EnterpriseBotTestRHW.csproj...
NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Bot.Builder from 4.0.8 to 4.0.6. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 EnterpriseBotTestRHW -> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs 4.0.8 -> Microsoft.Bot.Builder (>= 4.0.8) 
 EnterpriseBotTestRHW -> Microsoft.Bot.Builder (>= 4.0.6)
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'EnterpriseBotTestRHW'.

Comment: Try setting it to 4.0.8 in the .csproj

Comment: Ok, that worked.  Changing to 4.0.8 fixed NuGet update issue. Now I get a compilation error.  Line 68 of ContentModeratorMiddleware.cs which looks like "client.BaseUrl = $"{this.region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";" has a compiation error that says: "Error CS1061 'ContentModeratorClient' does not contain a definition for 'BaseUrl' ..."  It looks like the member name has changed.  Should that be changed to client.Endpoint = $"{this.region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"?

Comment: It appears so! I was using the v1.0.0 preview version of the Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator package, and had .BaseUrl. I upgraded the package to v1.0.0 and got the same compilation error. It is now Endpoint. Good find. Changing that line of code resolved it for me. Please try it out.